# Circle geometry proof

Tags: geometry

[image]

There are five circles in the diagram, each congruent to the other, with centres A, C, F, E, G. Line segments IO and NJ intersect at point Y, where angle NYO is equal to 60 degeees (hence, Y lies on the circumference of circle with centre A). A line is drawn from F to P. This line intersects the circumference of circle with centre A at two points. The first point being F. Let the second point be Z. Prove that Z lies on the circumference of a circle with centre Y (where AY is its radius), and hence, that Z occurs at an intersection point between the circumferences of circles with centre A and centre Y.

This proof should involve methods such as the alternate segment theorem, properties of cyclic quadrilaterals, properties regarding angles subtended by the same arc, etc. I'm having trouble figuring out what auxiliary lines to draw as well as which circles to consider. An answer to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is point $Q$? Why not introduce coordinates?

Comment: My bad, it was NYO. I hadn't thought of using coordinates mainly due to it being a problem involving circle theorems. May I ask what method would require coordinates? Thanks for picking up on the error.

Comment: Oh, I see. It would be easier to communicate the proof with coordinates. Which software would you recommend to create such a diagram?

Comment: My proof implicitly uses coordinates. For diagram, some people use [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) , Python, gnuplot, or Maple. I used Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circles centered at $A$ and $N$ intersect in two points. One is $F$ and call the other $B$.
We are given that line segments $IO$ and $NJ$ intersect at a new point $Y$.
Using affine linear combinations of the points $N,O,F$ we can express
any other points. For example, 
$$ I = 2F-N,\, J = -2N+\frac52 F+\frac12 O. $$
We find that point $Y$ satisfies
$$ Y = \frac57 I \!+\! \frac27 O = \frac37 N \!+\!\frac47 J =
  \frac{10}7 F \!+\! \frac27 O \!-\! \frac57 N. $$
Notice that $NFO$ forms a right triangle with hypoteneuse $OF$ which is twice the
length of line segment $NF$ and line segment $NO$ is $\,\sqrt{3}\,$ times the
length of line segment $NF$. Notice that point $A$ is the midpoint of line segment
$OF$. Now we calculate using the Pythagorean theorem that the length of line
segment $AY$ is the same that of $AF$ and thus the point $Y$ is on the
circumference of the circle centered at $A$.

Let line segments $BG$ and $FP$ intersect at a new point $Z$. This case is similar to the one for point $Y$. Just rotate the diagram by $60$ degrees around center point $A$.
That is, line segment $IO$ is rotated to $GB$ and $NJ$ is rotated to $FP$. Thus the
point $Y$ is rotated $60$ degrees around center point $A$. Thus, the three points
$\,A,Y,Z\,$ form an equilateral triangle. The diagram looks like this:

[image]

There may be other ways to get this result, but this is what I have now.